# Can we create an Action from a Dopesheet animation?

Tags: animation, node-editor, shaders, dopesheet, actions

I have animated a number of Shader Node properties and the keyframes show up in the Dopesheet but not in the Actions editor.
I have tried copying the keyframes from the Dopesheet but I can't paste them into the Action editor which throws an error: "No selected F-curves to paste into".

How can I create an Action from the Dopesheet keyframes?

Answer (score 1):

Actions are automatically created the first time an object receives a keyframe of any kind. That is, assuming an action has not already been created in advance for the purpose of animating said object. So there would not be a reason to create an action for a Dope Sheet animation, because one would already exist as soon as there was an animation. This connection could be made clearer through the Blender UI, granted, so I'm not surprised to see that people are often unclear about exactly when, or how, actions come into being.

Comment: That is the case for objects, armatures, etc. but not for shader node values. Their keyframes only appear in the dopesheet and no action is automatically created for them. In fact, even if you create a new action manually, keyframes added to the shader graph do not appear in the action editor, only the dopesheet.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you for this info. By the way, I too find it odd that pastings of keyframe data won't go anywhere unless at least one keyframe already exists in the destination location.